# How to substitute two columns with a condition in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has products, actions, quantity and price. If the action is "SELL", I need to consider the price 0 for the product and also invert the quantity.

What I've tried:

```py
import pandas as pd


def my_function(df):
    kwargs = {
        "quantity": lambda x: -x["quantity"] if "SELL" in str(x["action"]) else x["quantity"],
        "price (usd)": lambda x: 0 if "SELL" in str(x["action"]) else x["price (usd)"],
    }
    return df.assign(**kwargs)


input_df = pd.DataFrame({"product": ["APPLE", "APPLE", "BANANA"],
                         "action": ["  SELL  ", "  BUY  ", "  SELL  "],
                         "quantity": [1, 2, 3],
                         "price (usd)": [3, 5, 8],
                         })

result_df = my_function(input_df)

expected_df = pd.DataFrame({"product": ["APPLE", "APPLE", "BANANA"],
                            "action": ["  SELL  ", "  BUY  ", "  SELL  "],
                            "quantity": [-1, 2, -3],
                            "price (usd)": [0, 5, 0],
                            })
```

Somehow the conditions in my lambda expressions always return True and I also think that might be a simpler way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
s=input_df.action.str.contains('SELL')
input_df.quantity*=s.map({True:-1,False:1})
input_df["price (usd)"]*=~s
input_df
  product    action  quantity  price (usd)
0   APPLE    SELL          -1            0
1   APPLE     BUY           2            5
2  BANANA    SELL          -3            0
```

In function

```
def my(x):
...     s=x.action.str.contains('SELL')
...     x.quantity*=s.map({True:-1,False:1})
...     x["price (usd)"]*=~s
...     return (x)


out=my(input_df)
out
  product    action  quantity  price (usd)
0   APPLE    SELL          -1            0
1   APPLE     BUY           2            5
2  BANANA    SELL          -3            0
```

Comment: I would also use `x["price (usd)"] *= sells.map({True: 0, False: 1})` to make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The below code fixes it. I got the desired output.

```
def my_function(df):
    kwargs = {
        "quantity": df.apply(lambda x: -x["quantity"] if "SELL" in str(x["action"]) else x["quantity"], axis = 1),
        "price (usd)": df.apply(lambda x: 0 if "SELL" in str(x["action"]) else x["price (usd)"], axis = 1),
    }
    return df.assign(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Nice, that works. Just for the sake of readability I use axis="columns" instead of axis=1. Thanks Ramin. This definetely could be considered an answer, but I think the program got easier to understand with Yoben's.

Comment: @staticdev you didn't ask for a different program. you asked for help with your code. i helped you with your code. and with respect to things being "easier to understand", i'm not sure how his code is easier to read than the one you had. after seing his code, readability was my concern. in fact, i thought your code was easier to understand than his.